# Why does .split("\\") generate an exception?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String representing a directory, where `\` is used to separate folders. I want to split based on `"\\"`:

```
String address = "C:\\saeed\\test";
String[] splited = address.split("\\");
```

However, this is giving me a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`.

Comment: that is not nonsense exception it is totally sensible exception learn way to split then blame java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have suggested, you could use:

```
String[] separated = address.split("\\\\");
```

**or you could use:**

```
String[] separated = address.split(Pattern.quote("\\"));
```

Also, for reference:

```
String address = "C:\saeed\test";
```

will not compile, since `\s` is not a valid escape sequence. Here `\t` is interpreted as the tab character, what you actually want is:

```
String address = "C:\\saeed\\test";
```

So, now we see that in order to get a `\` in a `String`, we need `"\\"`.
  The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash since `\` is a special character in regex, and hence must be escaped. Once we put this in quotes, aka turn it into a `String`, we need to escape each of the backslashes, yielding `"\\\\"`.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method takes a regex. In regex, you need to escape the backslashes. And then for string literals in Java, you need to escape the backslash. In all, you need to use 4 backslashes:

```
String[] splited = address.split("\\\\");
```

Comment: @q99. Added an explanation.

Comment: thank you, I refreshed the page and saw the explanation, so I deleted my commnet

Comment: I have always hated the "\\\\". It looks so awkward:)

Comment: @PetarMinchev See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @PetarMinchev. Yeah, that's one issue with Java, that I also don't like.

Comment: @SteveP. Yeah that is a way, but I would rather use it in case I've a regex stored in a String reference. In this case, it's just more typing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\\\` instead of `\\`.

> The backslash(\) is an escape character in Java Strings.If you want to use backslash as a literal you have to type \\\\  ,as \ is also a escape character in regular expressions.

For more details click [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

`\` has meaning as a part of the regex, so it too must be quoted.  Try `\\\\`.

The Java will have at `\\\\`, and produce `\\` which is what the regex processor needs to obtain `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Use separators:

```
String address = "C:\saeed\test";
String[] splited = address.split(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
```